# State space representation of coupled nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system

I have a DH matrix (Denavit-Hartenberg) of a two link manipulator having differential equation of the form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\tau_1 \\ \tau_2
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1+k_2\cos\theta_2 & k_3+k_4\cos\theta_2
\\ k_5+k_6\cos\theta_2 & k_7
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\ddot{\theta}_1 
\\ \ddot{\theta}_2
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
k_8\dot{\theta}_2^2 - k_9\dot{\theta}_1\dot{\theta}_2
\\k_{10}\dot{\theta}_1^2
\end{bmatrix}+f(\theta_1,\theta_2)
$$

where $f$ is a nonlinear function. $k_i$ are constants

How can such a nonlinear coupled differential equation be expressed in state space form? How to decouple terms which contain product of both states?

Edit : I want to design a state observer for this, so wanted it to be represented in state space form.

Comment: You cannot state the linear state space representation without linearizing the system.

Comment: I am not having the main problem in linearizing it. Let's assume this question is linearized about some point. How to decouple the terms where the two states are multiplied?

Comment: The linearization automatically eliminates all terms that are nonlinear e.g. $ \dot{\theta}_1\dot{\theta}_2 $. In your question, you asked how to state the state space representation and this is what @LutzL has answered. What you want is to get the linear time-invariant form of the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an equation of the form 
$$
r=M(θ)\ddot θ+b(θ,\dot θ)
$$
Introduce $\omega = \dot θ$ to find the first order system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\dot θ\\\dot ω\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}ω\\M(θ)^{-1}(r-b(θ,ω))\end{bmatrix}
$$
provided the matrix $M(θ)$ is invertible.

Comment: But the new matrix that you formed still has theta and omega coupled in the function b. How to express this in dX/dt = AX+BU form?

Comment: You can't as the system is deeply non-linear. If you have the goal to construct a controller you should post it as relevant information in your question.

Comment: I want to design a state observer and controller. So I want to represent it in state space form.

Comment: @AniketSharma The first order differential equation in this answer is a state space form. Only it is nonlinear, so you would have to linearize it in order to obtain the form $\dot{x}=A\,x+B\,u$.